# Why won't this xlsx file open?

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to use the openpyxl module to take a spreadsheet, see if there are empty cells in a certain column (in this case, column E), and then copy the rows that contain those empty cells to a new spreadsheet. The code runs without traceback, but the resulting file won't open. What's going on?

Here's my code:

```
#import the openpyxl module
import openpyxl

#First create a new workbook & sheet
newwb = openpyxl.Workbook()
newwb.save('TESTINGTHISTHING.xlsx')
newsheet = newwb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')

#open the original file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('OriginalWorkbook.xlsx')

#create a sheet object
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

#Find out how many cells of a certain column are left blank, 
#and what rows they're in
count = 0
listofrows = []
for row in range(2, sheet.get_highest_row() + 1):
    company = sheet['E' + str(row)].value
    if company == None:
        listofrows.append(row)
        count += 1
print listofrows
print count

#Put the values of the rows with blank company names into the new sheet
for i in range(len(listofrows)):
    j = 0
    newsheet['A' + str(i+1)] = sheet['A' + str(listofrows[j])].value
    j += 1

newwb.save('TESTINGTHISTHING.xlsx')
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your program with a mock document. I was able to open my output file without problem. Your issues probably relies within your excel or openpyxl version.

Please provide your software versions in addition to your source document so I can look further into the issue.

You can always update openpyxl with:

```
c:\Python27\Scripts
pip install openpyxl --upgrade
```

Comment: I am running Excel 2008 (version 12). I think the problem lies there. I plan on upgrading my version of Excel soon.